# How to use two different Python versions (3.4 and 2.7) for QGIS scripting?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-3

I´m intending to learn scripting with python in QGIS, but I have a couple of questions.

I'm using Python 3.4 for learning which is installed in my laptop, but QGIS is using Python2.7

How could I work with both together?
Creating an enter in the PYTHONPATH like C:..........python27 (wherever it is into QGIS directory) and adding  a shebang    #!.....python27   at the begining of my scripts?

Is there another way to work with both versions ?

I´m using PyQT and the same question again. One designer in python3.4 installed and another one into the QGIS directory.

How do you work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran across this problem and came to a solution.  I added a question/answer post to add some insight to this problem: [Using PyQGIS, ArcPy, NumPy, SciPy Together in Windows Command Prompt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157864/using-different-python-installs-together-in-windows-command-prompt/157865#157865)